# Is it possible to delete/downgrade python packages from Google Colab?

Tags: python, networkx, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab, to test Keras models. A library I'm using (hyperopt) seems to misbehave with another library with a specific version (networkx == 2.1). It was mentioned that the latest version of hyperopt on the master branch of its repository has solved this problem, but it isn't working in my case.

I tried `!pip uninstall networkx`, followed by `!pip install networkx==1.11`, finally checking the version with

```
    import network x
    print(networkx.__version__)
```

Which still prints 2.1

Is it not possible to downgrade a package in Google Colab?

Error is similar to this: https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/pull/319

Running Python 3.

Comment: You might be getting that because you imported networkx before installing 1.11. Just restart your kernel and uninstall 2.1 and install 1.11 and then import networkx and it should work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That might be happening because you imported networkx before uninstalling 2.1. You can just restart the notebook and go through the uninstall step before importing networkx.

```
[1] !pip uninstall networkx -y
Uninstalling networkx-2.1:
  Successfully uninstalled networkx-2.1

[2] !pip install networkx==1.11
Collecting networkx==1.11
  Using cached networkx-1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from networkx==1.11)
Installing collected packages: networkx
Successfully installed networkx-1.11

[3] import networkx
[4] networkx.__version__
'1.11'
```